# Python Execution result depending on the environment

Tags: python

When this code is executed in the console, it produces a rootselt false, but if it is written in a file and executed in any environment, it will be true, why?

```
a = 399
b = 399
print(a is b)
#True
```

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary no, it says about interned objects, but it is executed in the console. And I mean, if you execute the same code in the console and in a different environment, the result will be different.

Comment: I got you, when a source code gets compiled, immutable objects like `int` and literal tuples can share the reference and it has no impact. Anyway I vote for reopen the question. It will be open again if others vote too

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary But where does what you say to my question? I asked that the same code is executed differently in different environments. And you tell me what I know and what has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary The question to which you dropped the link does not correspond to mine in any way. And I don’t understand why I should create a new question?

Comment: No , you didn't understand what I said. I said I get that your question is different so I vote for reopening this question. You don't have to ask a new one.

Comment: Your question is closed right now, I sent it to the review queue to make it open again.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, I just don't understand what should I do?)

Comment: nothing, just wait